# swiftui open view from menu button

Tags: button, view, menu, swiftui

I am trying to do something very basic, but I have been through the official tutorials, and through dozens of stack overflow posts. I am trying to open an activity from a menu button. I do want the standard navigation back arrow when I do this.

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Hello World!")
                            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    Menu {
                        Button(action: {
                            Activities()
                        }) {
                            Label("Activities", systemImage: "doc")
                        }
```

"Activities()" is my view. When I do this nothing happens. I have read in other posts that you cannot have a navigation link in a menu either, which would be fine if that worked. How do I programmatically open up a view so the back arrow works?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case where you want to open a view but can't use a NavigationLink directly you can use it in another place and activate it programmatically from the button via a State property:

```
@State private var isShowingDetailView = false
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            NavigationLink(destination: Activities(), isActive: $isShowingDetailView) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            Text("Hello World!")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                        Menu {
                            Button(action: {
                                isShowingDetailView = true
                            }) {
                                Label("Activities", systemImage: "doc")
                            }
                        }
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but that doesn't work? Navigation links don't work within menus. I already tried that. Unless I am missing something

Comment: @noone392 sorry I wasn't aware of this. I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked perfectly. I was having trouble understanding the State variables. One thing to note to make this work, the Navigation link, needs to be inside the Vstack or it won't show anything on the screen

Comment: Is this the only way? Looks ugly (but no choice if that's the case)